# _read from stdin in Visual studio 2015

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

reading from the console with

```
i = _read(_fileno(stdin), &c, 1);
```

behaves differently in VS 2013 and VS2015, when the last character of an input word has been read, and the 'return' key is due. Upon calling the line again

in VS2013 (and older versions) `c` will become `10` (end of line), and `_read` returns `1` (one byte read)

In VS2015 `c` will again be `10`, but `_read` returns `0`

Bug or feature ?

The following small console program shows some details:

```
// ConsoleApplication1.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    int i, j;
    char buf[128], buf2[128];

    /* in 2015 this will return 0 at reading '\n' */
    /* bug ? */
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_TEXT);
    /* this will return 1 at reading '\n' */
    //_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY);

    j = 0;
    printf("Input:\n");

    /* read characters from stdin until \n is hit */
    do {
        /* 3 lines excerpted from original program (ngspice simulator)*/
        do
            i = _read(_fileno(stdin), &c, 1);
        while (i == -1 && errno == EINTR);
        /**************************************************************/
        if (i==0)
            buf2[j] = '0';
        else if (i == 1)
            buf2[j] = '1';
        else
            buf2[j] = 'x';

        buf[j++] = c;

    } while (c != '\n');

    buf[j] = '\0';
    buf2[j] = '\0';
    /* repeat the input */
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    /* type return value of _read */
    /* last caracter is 0 in VC2015 and 1 in VC2013 */
    printf("%s\n", buf2);
    /* wait for user 'return' */
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

With VC2010 (and 2008, 2013) the output is

```
Input:
asdfghj
asdfghj

11111111
```

With VC2015 I get

```
Input:
asdfghj
asdfghj

11111110
```

Comment: What is the type of `c` and how is it declared and initialized? What else is happening in your program before it reaches this point?

Comment: If `_read` returns `0`, the value of `c` is indeterminate.  Actual byte values depend on the binary/text mode currently selected for the operating system file associated with the `stdin` stream.

Answer (score 0):

Bug, was fixed by Microsoft for the next Visual Studio 2015 CRT release